# Better way to work with the UPS API?

Tags: api, class, package, ups

Specifically, the [**UPS TradeAbility API**](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US) -- I'm trying to implement Denied Party screening into my lead processing/quotation web application. However, the TradeAbility API is a bear.

I've found some decent package classes for simple tracking, which I've implemented successfully. But I've seen nothing to support TradeAbility. [UPS-PHP](http://code.google.com/p/ups-php/) has it on their TODO list, but the author has shifted focus to a paid app (which doesn't support it either).

Any leads are appreciated.

Thanks.